# Pass additional arguments to a built-in function

Tags: argument-passing, julia

I'm pretty new on Julia and have a question that may appear simple. Say I have a function, which I will name `test(x::Vector, arg1, arg2)` where `x` is a vector of variables and the function has two arguments `arg1` & `arg2`.

I would like to optimize (minimize) the function `test` with respect to the vector `x`. I can't figure out how to use the optimize function from the `Optim` package that accepts two arguments values. In R, one may do as following:

```
optim(initial guest, test, arg1=value1,arg2=value2)
```

Is there a similar way to declare argument value in Julia?

Answer (score 4):

You can define another function that fixes the value of those arguments.

```
# Function to minimize
f(x::Vector, a, b) = (x[1] - a)^2 + (x[2] - b)^2

using Optim
g(x::Vector) = f(x, 3, 4)
optimize(g, [0.,0.])
```

You could also use an anonymous function (but it may be less efficient).

```
optimize(x -> f(x,3,4), [0.,0.])
```

Comment: Thank you! It's a workaround for my prolem for now. It'd be nice if  the Julia functions can take additionnal arguments values though.

Comment: This solution is considered idiomatic Julia. See https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl/issues/27.