# Error while doing optimization using Julia Optim

Tags: optimization, julia

I am trying to optimize a function in Julia using following code, but getting LoadError. can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code?

```
data = readdlm("RGPSLessData.csv", ';')
using Optim
function f(x::Vector,n11,E)
     return sum(-log((x[5] * dnbinom(n11, x[1], x[2]/(x[2]+E)) + (1-x[5]) * dnbinom(n11, x[3], x[4]/(x[4]+E)))))
end
res = optimize(x -> f(x,data[:,1],data[:,2]),[0.2,0.06,1.4,1.8,0.1])
```

Comment: Have a look at the [newton.jl test from the Optim.jl package](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Optim.jl/blob/master/test/newton.jl).

Comment: @rickhg12hs, thanks for replying. I am new to all this thing. can you tell me what all changes i have to do? thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do given that the `newton` method examples are so very different from your example code.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158142/pass-additional-arguments-to-a-built-in-function

Comment: @Vincent Zoonekynd thanks for replying, i have updated my code.. which i have updated in my question but still it is showing loadError please help me out..

Comment: hey @rickhg12hs, yes that newton example is different from my code. but i am trying to write my code using example given in this page [Optim](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Optim.jl)

Comment: Please refrain from changing your question so drastically:
if you have fixed part of the problem, it is preferable to add
an update at the end of your question 
with the partially corrected code and the remaining issues.
Your code should now work, at least with a few warnings
(but we do not have `data`, so we cannot be sure).
If it does not, check that you can call the function at the starting point,
`f([0.2,0.06,1.4,1.8,0.1],data[:,1],data[:,2])`,
and check the type of the columns in your dataframe, 
`typeof(data[:,1])`, `typeof(data[:,2])`.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd, hey sorry i have changed my question.. `data[:,1]` & `data[:,2]` both are `DataArray{Float64,1}`. I am not able to call `f([0.2,0.06,1.4,1.8,0.1],data[:,1],data[:,2])` it is showing **MethodError**

Comment: I do not see where `dnbinom` is defined, 
but I suspect that its first argument
should only contain integers.
Replacing `data[:,1]` with `int(data[:,1])`
may address the problem.

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd, may be i got the problem. Initially this code has been written in R language. In R `dnbinom` function is used for **Negative Binomial Distribution** and i think same function is not there in Julia. Julia has `NegativeBinomial` but with only 2 arguments, i have to pass 3 arguments. Can you tell me how to use `NegativeBinomial`?

Answer (score 0):

`dnbinom` isn't a function in Julia (in the comments it appears to be from R). Probability distributions are provided by the [Distributions.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl) package. Instead of

```
dnbinom(n11, x[1], x[2]/(x[2]+E))
```

You can use

```
pdf(NegativeBinomial(x[1], x[2]/(x[2]+E)), n11)
```